# Decompile erlang .beam files compiled without debug_info

Tags: patch-reversing, erlang

I have an app that use erlang .beam compiled files without debugging information.
Someone have some tips how to decompile or reverse engineering these?

Thanks in advance

Comment: "7.11  Is there a "reverse compiler" for BEAM files?" (http://www.erlang.org/faq/tools.html)

Comment: I already see it. But honestly did you understand how to pass to beam_lib arguments to obtain abstract_code?

Comment: Can't write comments, yet, so you get the link as an answer. The HelloMike challenge from the 9447 CTF was a beam file without debug_info. This writeup goes through the reversing process of the file: https://medium.com/@shanewilton/9447-ctf-2014-hellomike-writeup-ba812f012d5

Comment: Following your advice and link i get that i don't have debug_info and i get an empty file if i try to decompile it with the command: erl -noshell -eval ‘hipe:c(my_beam, [pp_beam]), init:stop().’ > my_beam.disas. Do you have a tip? i get this error: (no error logger present) error: "Error in process <0.0.0> with exit value: {fun
ction_clause,[{init,prepare_run_args,[{eval,[<<11 bytes>>,<<11 bytes>>,<<13 byte
s>>]}]},{init,map,2},{init,boot,1}]}\n"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get low-level bytecode source of .beam file with **beam_disasm:file(module_name)**

It's not easy to read it and takes time to figure it out. But it's much verbose and easier to comprehend than any real hardware assembly code. You can give it a try.

For example, if you have a .beam file called "my_module.beam", open *erl* and type

```
file:write_file("/tmp/my_module_disasm", io_lib:fwrite("~p.\n", [beam_disasm:file(my_module)])).
```

where *'/tmp/my_module_disasm'* is the path where you want to save the result.