# Erlang Source file generation from .beam file

Tags: decompile, erlang

I have Erlang application's beam files which I want to decompile.

Application is Compiled and build with 'debug_info' options. here is snippet of emake file to which is used to build application :

```
{"apps/my_app/src/*",   [debug_info, nowarn_export_all, {outdir, "apps/my_app/ebin"},{pa, "deps"},{parse_transform, lager_transform}, {parse_transform, events_transform}]}.
```

I have tried function from beam_lib module but getting following Error :

```
1>{ok,{_,[{abstract_code,{_,AC}}]}} = beam_lib:chunks(abc,[abstract_code]).
** exception error: no match of right hand side value {error,beam_lib,{not_a_beam_file,'abc.beam'}}
```

I have also tried solution mentioned in following post [Decompile erlang .beam files compiled without debug_info](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/8895/decompile-erlang-beam-files-compiled-without-debug-info)
 but Its not working for me. I'm getting following error :

```
1> file:write_file("/tmp/my_module_disasm", io_lib:fwrite("~p.\n", [beam_disasm:file(abc)])).
ok
```

/tmp/my_module_disasm file contains :

```
{error,beam_lib,{not_a_beam_file,'abc.beam'}}.
```

Anyone have Idea ?

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried using [recon:source/1](http://ferd.github.io/recon/recon.html#source-1)?
I think it does exactly what you need.
If you don't want to use it, at least you can get inspiration from [its source code](https://github.com/ferd/recon/blob/6e420aaa9bb8ee5ad376231f47698b9621811ef0/src/recon.erl#L496-L500):

```
-spec source(module()) -> iolist().
source(Module) ->
    Path = code:which(Module),
    {ok,{_,[{abstract_code,{_,AC}}]}} = beam_lib:chunks(Path, [abstract_code]),
    erl_prettypr:format(erl_syntax:form_list(AC)).
```

Comment: I had already tried it, you can see it in code snippets in post.

Comment: Looks like your module (`abc`) is not compiled. What does `code:which(abc).` return?

Comment: I have taken backup from live node. So I don’t think so it is not compiled. And code:which(abc) is returning absolute path of beam file.

Comment: Actually, on closer look, the error you're seeing comes from [here](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/21b920e38078412f3d47442b27b40b3601a1c7d7/lib/stdlib/src/beam_lib.erl#L568-L575), which means your file doesn't start with something like `FOR1____BEAM` (i.e. something that matches `<<"FOR1", _Size:32, "BEAM">>`.

Out of curiosity, can you show me the first 12 bytes of your abc.beam file?

Comment: here it is : <<69,82,76,50,62,12,178,214,62,207,41,11>> Or in printable format <<"ERL2>\f\262\326>\317)\v">>.

Comment: That's really strange. According to [this](http://www.erlang.se/~bjorn/beam_file_format.html) and other sources, `FOR1` is actually just a _Magic number indicating an IFF form. This is an extension to IFF indicating that all chunks are four-byte aligned._ and it's used to build and scan all .beam files since at least R13B03 (i.e. a long time ago). So, two more questions:

1. What does `abc:module_info().` return?
2. Any way you can share your beam file with us?

Comment: here is `abc:module_info().`
`[{module,abc},
 {exports,[...]},
 {attributes,[{vsn,[10...]},
              {declared_records,[]}]},
 {compile,[{options,[{parse_transform,events_transform},
                     compressed,
                     {source,"apps/***/src/abc.erl"},
                     {i,"apps/***/include"},
                     nowarn_export_all,
                     {d,production}]},
           {version,"2.0"},
           {source,".../src/abc.erl"}]},
 {native,false},
 {md5,<<75,214,244,246,35,73,154,180,70,208,143,93,40,
        254,32,143>>}]
`

Comment: I have truncated because of comment length limit. Can you suggest a way to share beam file.

Comment: To share the beam file, you can (among other possible solutions) upload it to a public repo on Github and paste the link here.

Comment: In any case, judging by the compile `options` reported by `abc:module_info().` (i.e. `[{parse_transform,events_transform}, compressed, {source,"apps/***/src/abc.erl"}, {i,"apps/***/include"}, nowarn_export_all, {d,production}]`), it looks like the module is not compiled with `debug_info`. But, if that would be the case, the reported error should be `no_abstract_code`.

Comment: Any solution? This solution also not working : https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/8895/decompile-erlang-beam-files-compiled-without-debug-info

Comment: No solutions yet, my friend. I must say your beam file is… interesting.
If I can get access to it, I might be able to find out more.

Comment: here is beam file : https://github.com/parmar7725274/beam

Comment: This is what happens when I try to load it:

https://gist.github.com/elbrujohalcon/bc93e6a6881b3395da2318f567b4638d

Is this not happening on your computer?

Comment: Out of curiosity I checked http://erlang.org/download/ and looked for the oldest available version of Erlang/OTP source code (i.e. R6B-0 - _…and that was a trip!_) but that one still has the same BEAM format (i.e. beam files are required to start with FOR1).

Comment: I also found [this](http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2007-January/025042.html) mail by Daniel Luna from 2007. But sadly, there is no answer.